# Disjointed bones in 3ds Max - Are they a problem?

Tags: animation, 3dsmax, skeletal-animation, rigging, biped

The title sums up my question fairly well. I'm working with a biped, and I'm not sure whether to put the extra effort into connecting all the bones, or just to leave spaces between each of them. What do you think?

Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/35ZsF.png

Comment: I'm likely to export this to unity, btw - though I'm unsure how much of a difference that makes.

Comment: ultimately, a bone is just a transform (a matrix). And as such it takes up no volume. It represents only a point in 3d space and a rotation. So actually, there is no such concept as 2 bones even touching each other than a way to help us visualize the way it affects our mesh transform hierarchy. They are visually connected on 3d modeling apps to show parent/child relationships. If you don't need that visual aid, there is no need to visually join your bones.

Comment: Thanks. That kinda-sorta makes me wish I could break up some of the more detailed systems (legs, arms). Perhaps I can, and I just haven't figured out how yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space or no-space between joints/bones are just cosmetic, and should not pose a problem. The placement of the pivot is the most important factor, it determines the origin of the rotation and should be chosen carefully.

I think you'll be fine. The mesh on the other hand seems very dense, it can affect performance greatly, especially deforming meshes.

Comment: Thanks :). Yeah, deformation is a bit of an issue - I sent the mesh off to a more-experienced friend so that they could go over and fix any issues.